# Deploying an SSL MVC 5 application to Shared Hosting - 403 Error

Tags: ssl, deployment, asp.net-mvc-5

I have uploaded my ASP.NET MVC 5 application to my Shared Hosting root directory (MVC apps would only work in root directory).

This is the first time that I have deployed something with SSL. My Host Provider gives me a Shared SSL Certificate. Inside my root folder I have another folder for the SSL encrypted stuff.

I am confused as to what I'm supposed to be putting inside the folder! I can't put my whole application in there because the site won't work unless placed in the root folder.

Also I'm not sure if I need to do anything locally with that SSL URL before I deploy my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the case with all shared hosting providers or some. Mine (Fasthosts) only allows MVC applications to run from /htdocs (root) and they give you a sub-folder for your SSL encrypted files.

But if you're whole application is using SSL, then it wouldn't work, cause you can't move your whole MVC application into the SSL sub-folder on the root.

Anyways I ended up getting a virtual dedicated server and bought my own SSL certificate.